# JQuery popup window (banner) example

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, modal-dialog, banner

I am newbie , I am trying to create popup window using jquery, but I have some problems. I need popup window with ad for example. It should have close button, should be fixed (while scrolling page) and prevent closing clicking outside. So I need popup window with close button, which will cause closing this window only.
Please give an example of implementation. I would be grateful for help.
Thank everyone in advance.

Comment: Look the bootstrap...you can use just the modals..

Comment: can you provide an example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an example how you could build a simple popup window

HTML Code

```
<div id="shadowbox"></div>
<div id="banner">
    <div id="close">Close X</div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="click" value="open Banner"><br><br>
<input type="button" id="test" value="Click">
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 1000px;
}

#shadowbox {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 998;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#banner {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    height: 360px;
    width: 720px;
    background: #FFF;
}

#close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

JQuery

```
 $('#close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $('#shadowbox').hide();
            //Function after window is closed 
            yourfunction(); 
});

//Your Function
function yourfunction() {
        alert('window has been closed');
}


$('#click').click(function() {
     $('#shadowbox, #banner').show();   
});

$('#test').click(function() {
    alert('Button was clicked');
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYBoRd

Comment: Thnak you for answer !!! Is it possible to listen on close event ?